# How to use regexp_like in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I want to match characters which start with `德州分公司.` and end with `公司`. My regular expression goes like:

```
  select *
    FROM SF_GROUP T
   where regexp_like(t.group_name,
                     '^德州分公司\.([' || unistr('\4e00') || '-' ||
                     unistr('\9fa5') || ']*)公司$');

-- or another try
                     
  select *
    FROM SF_GROUP T
   where regexp_like(t.group_name,
                     '^德州分公司\.([\u4e00-\u9fa5]*)公司$');
```

But neither of the above methods work. The characters to be matched(Chinese characters):

```
德州分公司.禹城分公司
德州分公司.齐河分公司
德州分公司.综合部
德州分公司.集团客户部
```

Records in my table:

[image]

Output I want to get:

[image]

However it returns nothing after I excute the sentence:

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Your first query appears to work [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d0e7de37a89116aa3ae68269bc68c8ad). Please explain what you mean by "neither of the above methods work" as that sentence does not tell us why you think they do not work, what output you do get and what your expected output is.

Comment: Sorry, I have edit my question and added some details of my operation.

Comment: @MT0 I tried your sentences and `regexp_like(t.group_name,
                   '^德州分公司\..*公司$')` works for me.

Comment: @MT0 But why `regexp_like(t.group_name,
                   '^德州分公司\.(['
                   || unistr('\4e00')
                   || '-'
                   || unistr('\9fa5')
                   || ']*)公司$')` did't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sf_group (group_name) AS
SELECT '德州分公司.禹城分公司' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '德州分公司.齐河分公司' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '德州分公司.综合部'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '德州分公司.集团客户部' FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT group_name,
       DUMP(group_name, 1010)
FROM   sf_group
```

Should output something like:

> | GROUP_NAME | DUMP(GROUP_NAME,1010) |
> | --- | --- |
> | 德州分公司.禹城分公司 | Typ=1 Len=31 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 229,190,183,229,183,158,229,136,134,229,133,172,229,143,184,46,231,166,185,229,159,142,229,136,134,229,133,172,229,143,184 |
> | 德州分公司.齐河分公司 | Typ=1 Len=31 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 229,190,183,229,183,158,229,136,134,229,133,172,229,143,184,46,233,189,144,230,178,179,229,136,134,229,133,172,229,143,184 |
> | 德州分公司.综合部 | Typ=1 Len=25 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 229,190,183,229,183,158,229,136,134,229,133,172,229,143,184,46,231,187,188,229,144,136,233,131,168 |
> | 德州分公司.集团客户部 | Typ=1 Len=31 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 229,190,183,229,183,158,229,136,134,229,133,172,229,143,184,46,233,155,134,229,155,162,229,174,162,230,136,183,233,131,168 |

If you are not seeing a UTF-8 character set then your issue may relate to the character set you are using to store the strings; you can try changing the column from a `CHAR` or `VARCHAR2` data type to `NCHAR` or `NVARCHAR2`.

---

> I want to match characters which start with `德州分公司.` and end with `公司`.

The simplest method, if you do not need to filter the intervening characters is not to use regular expressions but to use `LIKE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   sf_group
WHERE  group_name LIKE '德州分公司.%公司';
```

Which outputs:

> | GROUP_NAME |
> | --- |
> | 德州分公司.禹城分公司 |
> | 德州分公司.齐河分公司 |

If you want to filter the intervening characters then your first query works:

```sql
SELECT '^德州分公司\.(['
                   || unistr('\4e00')
                   || '-'
                   || unistr('\9fa5')
                   || ']*)公司$' FROM DUAL;
```

But you can also hardcode the characters that match `unistr('\4e00')` and `unistr('\9fa5')`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   sf_group
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(group_name, '^德州分公司\.[一-龥]*公司$')
```

and they both output:

```sql
> | GROUP_NAME                      |
> | :------------------------------ |
> | 德州分公司.禹城分公司 |
> | 德州分公司.齐河分公司 |
```

---

If your query is not working and you want to find the values it is not working for then you can use:

```sql
SELECT group_name,
       DUMP(
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.group_name, '^德州分公司\.(.*)公司$', 1, 1, NULL, 1),
         1016
       ) AS group_name_dump
FROM   SF_GROUP T
WHERE  -- Find the rows that match the start and end of the pattern.
       regexp_like(t.group_name, '^德州分公司\.(.*)公司$')
AND    -- Find the rows where the middle of the pattern does not match.
       NOT REGEXP_LIKE(
         -- Extract the middle capturing group
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.group_name, '^德州分公司\.(.*)公司$', 1, 1, NULL, 1),
         '^[' || unistr('\4e00') || '-' || unistr('\9fa5') || ']*$'
       );
```

---

The query:

```
select *
FROM   SF_GROUP T
where  regexp_like(t.group_name,
                   '^德州分公司\.([\u4e00-\u9fa5]*)公司$');
```

Will not work because the [Regular Expression Operator Multilingual Enhancements documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Regular-Expression-Operator-Multilingual-Enhancements.html#GUID-8A02D839-90A5-4FB6-AC43-7AE8CB08E8BA) states:

> Oracle lets you enter multibyte characters directly, if you have a direct input method, or you can use functions to compose the multibyte characters. You cannot use the Unicode hexadecimal encoding value of the form '\xxxx'. Oracle evaluates the characters based on the byte values used to encode the character, not the graphical representation of the character. All accented characters are considered word characters.

So `[\u4e00-\u9fa5]` matches either the character `\` or `u` oe `4` or `e` or `0` or the range `0-\` or `u` or `9` or `f` or `a` or `5`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4a2964b772f8ef5443d73d1b3aa69fdf)*

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM   sf_group
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(group_name, '^德州分公司\.[一-龥]*公司$')` still not worked, until I tried Alex Poole's approach and changed the session setting.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this one it should work:

select *
FROM SF_GROUP T
where regexp_like(t.group_name, '^德州分公司.(.*)公司$');

or you can use LIKE, do not need regular expression:

where t.group_name like('德州分公司%公司')

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to @MTO's fine answer and your comment under the question:

> But why ... did't work?

... when clearly it *did* work in the db<>fiddle MTO provided...

It's possible that your NLS session settings are affecting the outcome.

As noted [in the documentatation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Pattern-matching-Conditions.html), "the REGEXP_LIKE condition is collation-sensitive".

With binary collation the query returns the expected result, but it won't always with other settings. If you have `NLS_COMP` set to `'LINGUISTIC'` and `NLS_SORT` set to `'SCHINESE_RADICAL_M'` or `'SCHINESE_STROKE_M'` then the query still does what you expect; but if you have `NLS_SORT` set to `'SCHINESE_PINYIN_M'` then it won't return any data. That seems to be what you're seeing.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9e2892b8d7ed926efe0f23e0f34530b0) based on MTO's, adding the same query repeated with those three settings - showing results for the first two and no results for `'SCHINESE_PINYIN_M'`.

Read more about linguistic sorting [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/linguistic-sorting-and-matching.html).

You can change your session settings, or switch to the `.*` approach to match any characters between the strings you specified, or use `LIKE`; as MTO also showed.

Comment: I changed my seesion settting, and `regexp_like(t.group_name,                    '^德州分公司\.(['                    || unistr('\4e00')                    || '-'                    || unistr('\9fa5')                    || ']*)公司$')` finnaly worked. Thank you for the explanation.